# Is there any benefit of using docker for installing traditional MVC based web application?

Tags: docker

Today, I have a standard web (MVC) application that can be installed using the installer on the client PC. I am using Advance Installer for this purpose. I am planning to start decomposing this web app into micro-services based architecture so that this can be hosted in the cloud or on-premises. This journey will take more than year. I would be using the proper containerisation with dockers for the development and deployment in the future.

Only on the trial basis I want to test the deployment of my current monolithic web application using the docker host on the client PC. I know using docker will complicate the installation process. But still wanted to get some opinions on this.

Many thanks in advance !!

Comment: Useful note: "On-premises" and "on client PC" usually mean very different things. "On-premises" usually means a server installation that is offered as an alternative to cloud hosting.

Comment: For PC software, if you have a good quality GUI installer program, there may not be much advantage in using Docker - installs and updates can just be done using the installer. However, pulling Docker images would probably work. What advantages are you looking for?

Comment: I just want to make sure that the .Net framework and all the dependencies I have today are compatible with the docker and will just work. For the moment, I am not considering this for the production until I have decomposed the application to support microservices and are ready for cloud deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Well Docker is a containerization technology that is usually deployed as part of a service oriented architecture (SOA).

It is usually deployed on servers in a multi client configuration. But you may install it on a local computer for a single client.

If your application needs to be based on micro services, then you may implement the micro services in different ways. For example using APIs, Cloud services, Programming libraries etc. You should choose the tool that best satisfies your clients requirements.

Comment: You are right. My application is not based on the microservices model yet. This is the plan for the future. This is the reason I just wanted to ensure that the traditional monolithic MVC based web app can be deployed as a container image in the docker host on the client PC. Will there be any benefit doing that?

Comment: Well one benefit is that your MVC web app will be isolated from other software running on the client's computer. A drawback is that updating the app will not be straightforward. A better option could be to run your app within a virtual machine such as KVM or LXC/LXD containers. These are better suited for monolithic applications, while Docker is more suitable for microservices